# QTimer and active status

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, timer

Here is my situation:

I have connected what is follow:

```
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(avg()));
timer->start(5000);
```

the time computation of avg() is 1 second. So I should be having for the avg function, an average of 5 values.

Inside the avg() function , is it allowed to write, while the timer is active, it calculates average like above:

```
do
{ 
... // Saving all values, within the 5 seconds of timer and averaging them

}
while **(timer->isActive())**;
```

My question / inquiry : is the bold field (timer ->isActive()) means that the loop will work and make the treatments while the timer hasn't timedout from the fixed 5 seconds?

Comment: And what's your problem? The question seems to be incomplete.

Comment: @Riateche Please see the edit for the extra question that I have edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you're using `QTimer` totally incorrectly. Its purpose is not to measure time, but to call slots at specified time intervals. For example, if you call `start`, your slot will be called 5 seconds later, then it will be called again 5 seconds later, etc. `isActive` will be always true until you call `stop`.

`QElapsedTimer` will be more helpful for your purposes. Call `start` to initialize the timer. Check if you should terminate the procedure using `timer.elapsed() >= 5000`.